# Get a value from string using regular expression in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Im just trying to get a page count from a local pdf file. 
I converted the pdf to string and tried getting the page number from it.
I tried using regular expression. But im not able to perfect it.
So please help.

The below is the string text

```
 object(setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfDictionary)#2728 (1) { ["value"]=> 
 array(3) { ["Size"]=> object(setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfNumeric)#2726 
 (1) { ["value"]=> int(3028) } ["Root"]=> 
object(setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfIndirectObjectReference)#2725 (2) { 
["generationNumber"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> int(3027) } ["Info"]=> 
object(setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\Type\PdfIndirectObjectReference)#2731 (2) { 
["generationNumber"]=> int(0) ["value"]=> int(3026) } } } } } } 
["objects":protected]=> array(0) { } }
```

> ["pageCount":protected]=> int(96)

```
["pages":protected]=> array(0) { } } } ["currentReaderId":protected]=> 
string(71) 
"C:\xampp\files\journals\2\articles\13\submission\mergedpdf\allFiles.pdf" 
["importedPages":protected]=> array(0) { } ["objectMap":protected]=> 
 array(0) { } ["objectsToCopy":protected]=> array(1) { ["C:\xampp\files\journals\2\articles\13\submission\mergedpdf\allFiles.pdf"]=> 
array(0) { } } }
```

I need to get the pageCount displayed in blockquote using regularexpression.
The regular expression code below:

```
    ob_start();
    var_dump($pdf);//this was an object so i converted it to string for pattern matching.
    $result = ob_get_clean();//shows the result in string.
    $subject = "pageCount";
    $pattern = '/^pageCount/';//pattern to match to get page count
    preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,20), $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

print_r($matches);

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code!

Comment: ob_start();
  var_dump($pdf);
  $result = ob_get_clean();
  $subject = "pageCount";
                $pattern = '/^pageCount/';
                preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,20), $matches, 
                PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
                print_r($matches);

Comment: You don't need `regex` for this task. You need to learn some [basic OOP concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) and how they [can be used in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). And you also need to read the [documentation of FPDI PDF-Parser](https://manuals.setasign.com).

Comment: Check out this one:

https://regex101.com/r/RyGMwb/2

Comment: @Paladin i have included my code with an edit to the original post

Answer (score 1):

you could use [method](https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/c/SetaPDF.Core.Document.Catalog.Pages#method_count) provided by the library, like:

```
$filename = 'some-file.pdf';

require_once('library/SetaPDF/Autoload.php');
// or if you use composer require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$document = SetaPDF_Core_Document::loadByFilename($filename);

$pages = $document->getCatalog()->getPages();
$pageCount = $pages->count();
echo $pageCount;
```

Comment: what does SetaPDF_Core_Document mean?

Comment: @WiselyDCruizer Its name of a class that represents the PDF document. You can check the details in API reference https://manuals.setasign.com/api-reference/setapdf/

Comment: where can i get SetaPDF?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather loop through the object given instead of using regex for getting values out of it.

But if this is really what you need here is your regex: `\["pageCount":protected\]=> int\(\d*\)`

You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/RyGMwb/2

Comment: im not able to get the count